# How do I change a UILabel's text on a pushed (with segue) view, relative to the senders selected accessory?

Tags: iphone, ios, uistoryboard

I have a `UITableView` that pushes, via a storyboard segue, a view, which displays a `UILabel` that I wish to change the text on relative to the `indexPath.row` of the selected **accessory** on the `UITableView`.

I know it's probably wildly wrong, but this was my attempt. I feel like I'm going about it very wrong:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ArticlePreviewSegue" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [sender indexPathForSelectedRow];
    ArticlePreviewViewController *apvc = [segue destinationViewController];
    NSDictionary *article = [_newsFetcher.articles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    apvc.titleLabel.text = [article objectForKey:@"title"];
    apvc.bodyLabel.text = [article objectForKey:@"body"];
}
```

Thanks you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem may be that tapping the accessory doesn't select the row.  You can handle that by passing the index path as the sender of the segue:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ArticlePreviewSegue" sender:indexPath];
}
```

Now you can access the index path in `prepareForSegue:sender:` without relying on the row being selected.

Another problem is that in `prepareForSegue:sender:`, `apvc` hasn't loaded its view yet.  So `apvc.titleLabel` and `apvc.bodyLabel` are both nil.

The proper way to handle this is to give `ArticlePreviewViewController` an `article` property and set that property in `prepareForSegue:sender:`, like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = (NSIndexPath *)sender;
    ArticlePreviewViewController *apvc = [segue destinationViewController];
    apvc.article = [_newsFetcher.articles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

Then, in `-[ArticlePreviewViewController viewDidLoad]`, you can set the labels based on the article:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.titleLabel.text = self.article[@"title"];
    self.bodyLabel.text = self.article[@"body"];
}
```

Comment: Oh I did try this at one point and it wasn't working, but reading your answer made me realise a mistake I'd made when trying this approach! Thank you for the answer :)